# Need help to group the record from DB in java

Tags: java, collections

I have a result as follows :

```
tablename   columnname     size    order
employee    name            25      1
employee    sex             25      2
employee    contactNumber   50      3
address     name            25      4
address     street          25      5
address     country         25      6
```

this is my java code to group values based on `table name`

```
public void getReportQuery() {
    String tablename="",columnname="";
    int size=0,order=0;
    boolean isCustomised=true;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> reportQueryMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
    List<String> reportQueryTableNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Connection connection = getConnection();
    if (connection != null) {
       try {
         sb.append("SELECT rmaster.tablename,rmaster.columnname,r.size,r.order FROM report_customise_child r,report_customise_master rmaster where r.isactive='y' and rmaster.id=r.masterid; ");
         PreparedStatement reportQueryPS = connection.prepareStatement(sb.toString());
                ResultSet reportQuery_rst= reportQueryPS.executeQuery();
    if(reportQuery_rst!=null){
     while (reportQuery_rst.next()) {
       tablename = reportQuery_rst.getString("tablename");
        if (!reportQueryTableNameList.contains(tablename)) {
            reportQueryTableNameList.add(tablename);
        System.out.println("tablename : "+tablename);
                        }
                            columnname = reportQuery_rst.getString("columnname");
                            System.out.println(" columnname : "+columnname);

                            //size = reportQuery_rst.getInt("size");
                            //order = reportQuery_rst.getInt("order");
                  }
                }else{
                    isCustomised=false;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    closeConnection(connection, null, null);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Connection not Established. Please Contact Vendor");
        }
    }
```

I really don't know how to group the values and i want to construct the query from the above results like.

Please help me to group the values i shall construt the query from the grouped values.

I need to group like follows

```
tablename1
columnmaes

tablename2
columnnames

tablenameN
columnnames
```

Please help me to achieve this,

Regards

Comment: Do you need other values as well ?  I mean.. size and order

Comment: @Rp thanks for the effort,yes, but it will be usefull if i get them separate collection like column name and order and size.

Comment: Change query to `SELECT rmaster.tablename,rmaster.columnname,r.size,r.order FROM report_customise_child r,report_customise_master rmaster where r.isactive='y' and rmaster.id=r.masterid order by rmaster.tablename; `

Comment: 25 characters for "sex"? ...kinky...

Comment: @Philipp it is sample record not the original one, just for testing, Please avoid this kind of comment,ask for clarifications if you have any issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `Map<String, List<String>>` where key would be the table name and value would be the list of column names.

```
Map<String, List<String>> resultsMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
ResultSet reportQuery_rst= reportQueryPS.executeQuery();
if(reportQuery_rst!=null){
   while (reportQuery_rst.next()) {
      String tableName = reportQuery_rst.getString("tablename");
      List<String> columns = resultsMap.get(tableName); 
      if(columns == null ) { 
          columns = new ArrayList<String>();
          resultMap.put(tableName, columns);
      }
      columns = resultsMap.get(tableName);
      String columnName = reportQuery_rst.getString("columnname");
      columns.add(columnName);
   }
}
```

Now the `resultsMap` will have tableNames vs ColumnNames.
If you want to store the other information like order and size, You need to create a bean and store them against the table names like `Map<String, List<YourBean>>`.

**UPDATE**

Now, you want to prepare different queries with different table names out of this `resultMap`,

```
List<String> queries = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Entry<String, List<String>> resultEntry : resultMap.entrySet()) {
   String tableName = resultEntry.getKey();
   List<String> columns = resultEntry.getValue();
   StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder(" select ");
   int i = 0;
   for(String column : columns) {
       query.append(column);
       if(i != columns.size()) {
          query.append(", ");
       } 
       i++;
   }
   query.append(" from ").append(tableName);
   queries.add(query.toString());
}
```

Now `queries` will have all the require queries, As you have several queries, You need to take care of `Connection pooling` and all, Try to use something like `JDBC Templates` which will provide most of the common required operations like `DataSource, Connection pool, Automatic Bean Mapping` etc.
Hope this helps your.

Comment: No Problem, Shoot your question

Comment: Thanks, Now i have table name and column names, how to construct a select query from the resultMap?, Like SELECT employee.name,...from employee employee,address address. sorry for wasting your valuable time.

Comment: Updated my answer, this will give just a heads-up.

Comment: it gives me two query but i need to have only one query

Comment: You have two different tablenames hence it is giving two different queries, You want to `join` those two tables ? like `select few columns from first, few columns from second from first_table inner join second_table on some condition` ??